# how to broadcast a sympy lambdify generated function?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, sympy

I'd like to compute a Sympy expression as a function of two of the symbols in it. A function of 1 variable can readily be broadcast-ed after lambdifying it:

```
x, y, z = symbols('x y z')
expr = x*y + z
f = lambdify(x, expr.subs({z:2, y:4}))
x = np.linspace(1, 4, 5)
f(x)
```

But is there a way to use some builtin capability of numpy or sympy to broadcast higher dimensionally? In other words, is there a more direct or cleaner way to do the following?

```
x, y, z = symbols('x y z')
expr = x*y + z
f = lambdify([x, y], expr.subs({z:2}))
def g(xy):
    k = xy.shape[1]
    a = np.ndarray((k,k))
    for j in range(k): 
        for i in range(k):
            a[j, i] = f(xy[0, j], xy[1, i])
    return a

            
x = np.linspace(0, 4, 5)
y = np.linspace(10, 12, 5)
xy = np.array([x,y])  
g(xy)
```

Comment: `lambdify` does a shallow lexical translation.  Look at `f.__doc__` (it's help)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to get the shapes right for broadcasting:

```
In [11]: x, y, z = symbols('x y z')
    ...: expr = x*y + z
    ...: f = lambdify([x, y], expr.subs({z:2}))

In [12]: x = np.linspace(0, 4, 5).reshape((5, 1))

In [13]: y = np.linspace(10, 12, 5)

In [14]: f(x, y)
Out[14]: 
array([[ 2. ,  2. ,  2. ,  2. ,  2. ],
       [12. , 12.5, 13. , 13.5, 14. ],
       [22. , 23. , 24. , 25. , 26. ],
       [32. , 33.5, 35. , 36.5, 38. ],
       [42. , 44. , 46. , 48. , 50. ]])
```

Answer (score 1):

`help(f)` (or `print(f.__doc__)`) shows:

```
Help on function _lambdifygenerated:

_lambdifygenerated(x, y)
    Created with lambdify. Signature:
    
    func(x, y)
    
    Expression:
    
    x*y + 2
    
    Source code:
    
    def _lambdifygenerated(x, y):
        return (x*y + 2)
```

The `python/numpy` function just does `x*y+2`.  That's a simple translation of the `sympy`.  Use standard `numpy` array broadcasting.

For example a (3,1) array with (2,) produces a (3,2) result:

```
In [35]: np.arange(3)[:,None] * np.arange(10,12) + 2
Out[35]: 
array([[ 2,  2],
       [12, 13],
       [22, 24]])

In [36]: f(np.arange(3)[:,None], np.arange(10,12))
Out[36]: 
array([[ 2,  2],
       [12, 13],
       [22, 24]])
```